# git switch and come back to/from an older state

Tags: git, git-checkout, revert

I need to switch to an older commit to check an older functionality of our program that has been later removed.

For that I checkout the corresponding commit:

```
git checkout 367af0345d0b09ab3ade1c7856462f68e5eafe86
```

Then I change some code about this deprecated functionality. But this is just for checking I want to ignore all of them.

Now the verification is done I want to come back to the latest working code:

```
git checkout master
```

But unfortunately I get a warning that sounds bad:

```
git checkout master
Checking out files: 100% (281/281), done.
Warning: you are leaving 183 commits behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  367af03 message
  e5eee29 message
  6999d77 message
 ... and 179 more.

If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch new_branch_name 367af0345d0b09ab3ade1c7856462f68e5eafe86

Switched to branch 'master'
```

Indeed I want to keep the last 183 commits but I don't want to create a new branch, just come back to the state I was before reverting temporarily...

The thing is that now these 183 commits are actually present in my code so they have not been lost like the warning suggests.

What did I miss?

Comment: (1) how did you come up with `367af0345d0b09ab3ade1c7856462f68e5eafe86` in the first place? (2) if you try `git branch --contains 367af0345d0b09ab3ade1c7856462f68e5eafe86` and `git tag --contains 367af0345d0b09ab3ade1c7856462f68e5eafe86`, do either one print something?  The warning means that at least the `branch --contains` output must be empty...

Comment: I came up with this commit hash graphically on github. The two git branch `return `* master` and the git tag output is empty.

Comment: That's odd then: if `367af03...` is contained in `master`, `git checkout` should not have complained, and should just have said that it was moving to `master` and that the previous HEAD was detached at that SHA-1.

Answer (score 0):

You checked out a revision and git surely told you:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
>   changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
>   state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
>   do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
>
> git checkout -b new_branch_name

Then, you did some commits in this **detached HEAD** state which are not present on any branch.

Then, you checked out `master` again leaving these commits behind.

What to do depends on what you need:

- If you just wanted to check something, then everything is fine. The dangling commits will be cleaned up by `git gc`
- If you need the commits (e.g. if `367af0` points to a released version of your software and you are creating a fix for this old release), then you should do what git tells you: check out a new branch that holds these fixes

For the future, if you just want to play around on a certain revision, directly after `git checkout <REVISION>`, do a `git checkout -b tmp_playing_around` or something like that in order to avoid the problem with the detached head state.

Comment: Mmmmh after checkouting the detached HEAD I brought some modifications to the code but did not commit anything. What I did, according to my history, is stashing and commiting some stuff without pushing the changes to the server and **only after that** checkouted the detached HEAD. Could it be the reason I got this?